# Flutter Cloud Firestore Map<String, dynamic> error

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I am trying to build an app using Flutter and Firestore. When loading a Collection from Firestore using StreamBuilder to display it in a ListView, I get the following error

```
The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state:
I/flutter (26287): _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#d5638):

I/flutter (26287): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

I/flutter (26287): where

I/flutter (26287):   _InternalLinkedHashMap is from dart:collection

I/flutter (26287):   Map is from dart:core

I/flutter (26287):   String is from dart:core
```

This is how I want to get data from the `DocumentSnapshot`

```dart
class Creator {
  const Creator({this.creatorId, this.name});

  Creator.fromDoc(DocumentSnapshot doc) : this.fromMap(doc.data);

  Creator.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) :
    assert(map.containsKey('creatorId'),
    assert(map.containsKey('name'),
    this ( creatorId: map['creatorId'], name: map['name'] );

  /*

  ...

  */
}
```

And how I want to use it

```dart
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: new Text('Creators')),
  body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: CreatorRepo.getCreators().map<List<Creator>>((creators) {
      return creators.documents.map<Creator>((c) => Creator.fromSnapshot(c)).toList();
    }),
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if ( snapshot.hasData ) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          builder: (context, index) {
            final creator = snapshot.data[index];

            return ExpansionTile(
              title: Text(creator.name),
              children: [
                Text(creator.creatorId),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      }

      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  ),
);
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cloud_firestore: ^0.6.3
  firebase_messaging: ^0.2.4
```

Firestore only allows for `String` keys and `dynamic` values being, with the exception of `Timestamp`, core language types. The `cloud_firestore` plugin keeps document data in an `_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>`. I thought that the `Map` inside all `DocumentSnapshot` would be `Map<String, dynamic>`. How can I work around this? Changing all functions to take `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` and assume the key is a `String` is a rather ugly workaround to the problem.

Comment: What Flutter version are you using?

Comment: Ensure you only have `'package:...`;` imports in `lib/main.dart`

Comment: First try a `flutter clean` from the command line. If the problem persists, please post a few lines from the stack trace so we can see any line numbers etc. I've had similar problems being told that `_InternalLinkedHashMap` isn't a `Map` (despite all indications to the contrary!), but have always been able to get around them by a simple copy. If we can see where the exception is getting thrown, I'm sure we can come up with a workaround.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am currently not on my pc but I ran flutter upgrade yesterday. So I would say the current beta.

Comment: Also check you have the latest version of all other dependencies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is because the Map returned from Firebase is not a `Map<String, dynamic>` but instead `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`.

See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17417 for a related issue.

Answer (score 6):

Use `Map<String, dynamic>.from ( mapFromFirestore )`. This creates a new `Map<String, dynamic>` from the contents of `mapFromFirestore`, throwing an error if it finds a key that isn't a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

I too had this problem and fixed it with --

```
  Map<String, dynamic> var = {'item': 0, 'name': 'John'}
```

instead of Map unspecified.

```
  Map var = {'item': 0, 'name': 'John'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flutter now worked with `Map<String,String>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var stringMap = mapFromFirestore.map((key,value) => MapEntry(key as String, dynamic.from(value));
```