# Array type Field in firestore document to be converted to List of custom objects

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Data on my firebase looks like this: 
[image]

I want to convert the LIST_OF_ALL_COLLEAGUES into a List but I am unable to figure out how to do it.

I have a user class which has this List colleagues field.
My conversion code for user class looks like this:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:snagsnapper/Contants/constants.dart';
import 'package:snagsnapper/Data/colleague.dart';

class User {
  User ({
    this.name,
    this.dateFormat,
    this.listOfALLColleagues,
  });

  String name;
  String dateFormat='dd-MM-yyyy';
  List<Colleague> listOfALLColleagues;

  User.fromMap(DocumentSnapshot data)
      : this(
    name: data[NAME],
    dateFormat: data[DATE_FORMAT],
    listOfALLColleagues: List<Colleague>.from(data[LIST_OF_COLLEAGUES]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJSON() => {
    NAME : name,
    DATE_FORMAT : dateFormat,
    LIST_OF_COLLEAGUES : listOfALLColleagues,
  };

}
```

My Colleague class looks like the following:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:snagsnapper/Contants/constants.dart';

class Colleague {
  String name;
  String email;
  String phone;
  String uniqueID;

  Colleague({
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.phone,
    this.uniqueID,
  });

  Colleague.fromMap(DocumentSnapshot data)
      : this(
    name: data[NAME],
    email: data[EMAIL],
    phone: data[PHONE],
    uniqueID: data[UID],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJSON() => {
    NAME : name,
    EMAIL : email,
    PHONE : phone,
    UID : uniqueID,
  };
}
```

I have tried several methods I have seen online upto now but with no luck:
I have tried:

```
listOfALLColleagues: List<Colleague>.from(data[LIST_OF_COLLEAGUES]),
listOfALLColleagues: List.from(data[LIST_OF_COLLEAGUES]),
listOfALLColleagues: List.castFrom(data[LIST_OF_COLLEAGUES]),
listOfALLColleagues: data[LIST_OF_COLLEAGUES] as List<Colleague>,
listOfALLColleagues: data[LIST_OF_COLLEAGUES]
        .map((value) {
          return Colleague.fromMap(value);
        }).toList(),
```

I know some of these are same things but I just want to mention them here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Cloud Firestore Map<String, dynamic> error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159766/flutter-cloud-firestore-mapstring-dynamic-error)

Comment: Thanks. It seems I need to manually convert Colleague. But I am struggling to understand how to do it in code.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it with Json-Serial library. I wasn't aware of this library earlier and it I found it so much easier this way.