# type '_MapStream<QuerySnapshotPlatform, QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>?'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I get this error when i am trying to get data from firestore. I want to get individual values. I am getting following error;

```
type '_MapStream<QuerySnapshotPlatform, QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' is not a 
subtype of
type 'Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>?'
```

code is;

```
 class _userState extends State<user> {

 late final _fireS;
  String id = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
```

void initState() {
super.initState();

```
setState(() {
  _fireS = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('user')
      .doc(id).collection('details')
      .snapshots();
});
```

}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
return Scaffold(
  body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: _fireS,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
  if (snapshot == null || snapshot.data == null){

    return Text('something went wrong');
  } else {




    Map data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
 
   var user = data['plan'];
    return Text(user.toString());
  }}
  ));
```

}}

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50360552/12512650) answer in a similar thread. Please let me know if it helps.